# How to conditional format a column if the cell values are in another column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

if I have 2 columns(E: F:) and I want to find out if the values in one column(F:) are present in the other column(E:), using conditional formatting, how do I do this?

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F2PSuFEKB7bdDMznzRdzWrvcxWJFJjVRf0gobUXzuJ8/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

this is the conditional formatting I have tried so far:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `MATCH()` formula.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(F1,E:E,0))
```

[image]